# XPath/XSLT/Axes select all siblings including self

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, axes

It seems logical to me that there would be an easy axis or something else to select the text of all siblings, including self, but I can't seem to find it.

XML:

```
<panelTabs>
 <field></field>
 <field></field>
</panelTabs>
```

I'm currently in a `<xsl:template match="panelTabs/field>`, and I need to be in this template. I want to check whether or not all of the values within every `<field>` are empty, How do I do this?

**Edit:**
To be a little more specific. I would like my XSLT to be something like this:

```
<xsl:template match="panelTabs/field>
 <xsl:if test="allfieldshaventgottext = true">
  <p>All are empty</p>
 </xsl:if>
 <xsl:if test="thereisafieldwithtext = true">
  <p>There is a field with text</p>
 </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Instead of an `xsl:if`, an `xsl:when` will do

**EDIT:**

I created a new, more explained question. I'ts here: [XPath/XSLT select all siblings including self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418188/xpath-xslt-select-all-siblings-including-self)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `../*` to select all siblings including the current element (or `../field` to specifically select `field` elements).

So in your case, you could do:

```
<xsl:template match="panelTabs/field">
 <xsl:if test="not(../field[normalize-space()])">
  <p>All are empty</p>
 </xsl:if>
 <xsl:if test="../field[normalize-space()]">
  <p>There is a field with text</p>
 </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

[Example with some non-blank](http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/6avwnk/2)

[Example with all blank](http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/6avwnk/3)

However, it would be more idiomatic to use pattern matching:

```
<xsl:template match="panelTabs/field">
  <p>All are empty</p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="panelTabs[field[normalize-space()]]/field" priority="2">
  <p>There is a field with text</p>
</xsl:template>
```

[Example with some non-blank](http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/KsOk2I/3)

[Example with all blank](http://www.xsltcake.com/slices/KsOk2I/2)

If you only want to check once whether all of the fields are blank, you can do this:

```
<xsl:template match="panelTabs[not(field[normalize-space()])]">
  <p>All are empty</p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="panelTabs/field">
  <p><xsl:value-of select="." /></p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="panelTabs/field[not(normalize-space())]" priority="2" />
```

Comment: The first solution doesn't seem to work. It returns nothing while it should return something. I forgot to say there may be a space between the field tags. `<field> </field>`. I'll try the second solution.

Comment: If there's space between them, then `normalize-space()` will take care of that. `string()` will not.

Comment: The solutions don't work. Problem is, it returns `<p>All are empty</p>` two times.

Comment: @Grafit that is correct for the question you've asked - the template fires once for each `field`, and outputs `<p>All are empty</p>` if all the sibling fields are empty.  If you only want one "nothing" response _per panelTabs_ rather than one per field then you need to move the `if` up another level.

Comment: @IanRoberts You're right, my question was wrong. I'll move it up one template.

Comment: @Grafit There was a mistake in my second example (the contents of the templates were backwards). If you only want to display "All are empty" once, I've modified my answer to show how to do that.

Comment: @JLRishe This doesn't still really do what I wanted to. I'll create a new question with some more explanation. Still, thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you check `not(../field[not(normalize-space())])` then you know there is no field that is empty or simply contains white space.