# XPath/XSLT select all siblings including self

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, nodes, axes

I want my XSLT check to check whether or not all `<field>` in a random panelTabs are empty. If they are all empty, I want it to return `<p>All are empty</p>`, but if they are not, I want the content of the panelTabs with the fields to be inside the `<div id='tabItems'>`, the one with the same position as in the XML. Please help me.
XML:

```
<document>
 <contentTabs>
  <panelTabs text='a'>
   <row type='header'>
    <column>H1</column>
    <column>H2</column>
   </row>
   <row type='data'>
    <column>D1</column>
    <column>D2</column>
   </row>
  </panelTabs>
  <panelTabs text='b'>
   <field> </field>
   <field> </field>
  </panelTabs>
  <panelTabs text='c'>
   <field>x1</field>
   <field>x2</field>
  </panelTabs>
 <contentTabs>
</document>
```

Current XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match='contentTabs'>
 <ul id='ulTabKopjes' class='tabKopjes'>
  <li onclick='verschuifTabs(this)'>&#60;</li>
   <xsl:call-template name='liHeaders' />
  <li onclick='verschuifTabs(this)'>&#62;</li>
 </ul>
 <div class='tabContent'>
  <xsl:apply-templates />
 </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name='liHeaders'>
 <xsl:for-each select='panelTabs'>
  <li onclick='loadPanelTabContent(this)'>
   <xsl:value-of select="@text" />
  </li>
 </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="panelTabs">
 <div class="tabItems">
  <xsl:attribute name="id">
   <xsl:text>tabnr</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="position()" />
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:apply-templates />
 </div> 
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="panelTabs[not(field[normalize-space()])]">
 <p>All are empty</p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="panelTabs/field">
 <p><xsl:value-of select="." /></p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="panelTabs/field[not(normalize-space())]" priority="2" />
```

Only tried the XSLT without the last `<panelTabs>`

Wanted output, something like:

```
<ul id='ulTabKopjes' class='tabKopjes'>
 <li onclick='verschuifTabs(this)'>&#60;</li>
 <li onclick='loadPanelTabContent(this)'>a</li>
 <li onclick='loadPanelTabContent(this)'>b</li>
 <li onclick='loadPanelTabContent(this)'>c</li>
 <li onclick='verschuifTabs(this)'>&#62;</li>
</ul>
<div id='tabContent'>
 <div class='tabItems' id='tabnr1'>
  <table>something</table>
 </div>
 <div class='tabItems' id='tabnr2'>
  <p>All fields are empty</p>
 </div>
 <div class='tabItems' id='tabnr3'>
  <p>x1</p>
  <p>x2</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add a `panelTab` with fields having some values and show the expected output for that too..

Comment: @LingamurthyCS I edited the XML and wanted output of my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this stylesheet:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match='contentTabs'>
        <ul id='ulTabKopjes' class='tabKopjes'>
            <li onclick='verschuifTabs(this)'>&#60;</li>
            <xsl:call-template name='liHeaders' />
            <li onclick='verschuifTabs(this)'>&#62;</li>
        </ul>
        <div class='tabContent'>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name='liHeaders'>
        <xsl:for-each select='panelTabs'>
            <li onclick='loadPanelTabContent(this)'>
                <xsl:value-of select="@text" />
            </li>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="panelTabs">
        <div class="tabItems">
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:text>tabnr</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="position()" />
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="field and field = ''">
                    <p>All are empty</p>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:apply-templates />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </div> 
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="panelTabs/field[.!='']">
        <p><xsl:value-of select="." /></p>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="panelTabs/row">
        <table>something</table>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This seems to work, the only problem is that all content of all panelTabs (except the one with the empty fields) is printed twice.

Comment: NVM, I fixed this, this was another problem. Works great, thanks a lot! Is there an easy way to make this work when there are a variable amount of empty fields?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following.
Note that your output isn't well formed XML. If you want it to be well formed please add a root element.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match='contentTabs'>
    <ul id='ulTabKopjes' class='tabKopjes'>
        <li onclick='verschuifTabs(this)'>&#60;</li>
        <xsl:call-template name='liHeaders' />
        <li onclick='verschuifTabs(this)'>&#62;</li>
    </ul>
    <div class='tabContent'>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </div>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name='liHeaders'>
    <xsl:for-each select='panelTabs'>
        <li onclick='loadPanelTabContent(this)'>
            <xsl:value-of select="@text" />
        </li>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="panelTabs">
    <div class="tabItems">
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:text>tabnr</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </div>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="panelTabs[field[normalize-space() = '']]">
    <div class="tabItems">
        <p>All fields are empty</p>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="panelTabs[not(field)]">
    <div class="tabItems">
        <table>something</table>
    </div>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="panelTabs/field">
    <p>
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </p>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```